# I need to give 2 objects as a parameter in a constructor, but I'm struggling to find the right way to do it

Tags: java, object, parameters, constructor

```
public class Phone{

public String kind;
public String number;

    public Phone(String kind, String number) {
        this.kind = kind;
        this.number = number;
    }
}

public class ContactData{

public String eMail;

    Phone phone = new Phone("phone", "031234567");
    Phone cellphone = new Phone("cellphone", "0499209802");

    public ContactData(String eMail, Phone phone, Phone cellphone){
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
    }
}
```

[image: I've tried a lot of things but I keep getting this error]

Comment: What kind of 2nd and 3rd arguments does your `ContactData` constructor expect? What kind are you passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a type mismatch between constructor parameters and what you are actually passing:

```
public ContactData(String eMail, Phone phone, Phone cellphone)
```

However you are using a `String` object instead of a `Phone`:

```
new Contact("ab@abc.com","123","123");
```

What you really need to pass is an instance of `Phone`:

```
new Contact("ab@abc.com",new Phone("phone", "031234567"),
            new Phone("phone", "031234567"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your picture you are trying to declare a ContactData instance using a constructor with (String, String, String) parameters, but the only constructor you have takes a (String, Phone, Phone).

You can fix this by creating Phone instances when declaring the ContactData instance directly, like this:

```
ContactData contactData1 = new ContactData("nelson@hotmail.be", new Phone("cellphone", "154789562"), new Phone("cellphone", "1234567890"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought it would be something like this, but I couldn't find it!!